# Tomcat programmatic deployment using servlet without restart

Tags: java, tomcat

I would like to create a web project in java that can create servlet project(like ide) automatically.I done servlet project creation part but while my application in run i need to deploy the newly created project on the server.

how can i obtain this give some examples or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out your Tomcat's version hot deploy via `autoDeploy` of `server.xml`
[Tomcat Automatic_Application_Deployment](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic_Application_Deployment)

Answer (score 0):

If you are building using maven (and you really should be) this is pretty simple.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://myHost:8080/manager/html</url>
                <server>localtomcat</server>
                <update>true</update>
                <path>/myApp</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Then on the command line

```
mvn clean package tomcat:deploy
```

which will uninstall current version, and deploy the new version all nicely packaged in a war file

Answer (score 0):

You can do in several ways. One of the ways is to do using ANT if this is familiar to you (this assumes you are not hot deploying but doing programmatic deployment)

```
<project name="ApplicationName" basedir="." default="redeploy">

<!-- Defining the properties for this build.xml -->
<property environment="sysenv" />
<property name="application.war" value="<ApplicationName>.war"/>
<property name="server.home" value="${sysenv.CATALINA_HOME}"/>
<property name="server.startup" value="startup.bat"/>
<property name="server.shutdown" value="shutdown.bat"/>  
<property name="server.deploy" value="${server.home}/webapps"/>


<!-- Moves the application war file to server deployment folder -->
<target name="moveOutputWar">
    <echo>Deleting already deployed war file in the server</echo>
            <delete file="${server.deploy}/${application.war}"/>

    <copy file="${application.war}" toDir="${server.deploy}"/>  
</target>   

<!-- Restarts the server -->
<target name="redeploy" depends="moveOutputJar">
<echo>Stopping the server</echo>
<exec executable="${server.home}/bin/${server.shutdown}" dir="${server.home}/bin"/>
<echo>Starting the server</echo>
<exec executable="${server.home}/bin/${server.startup}" dir="${server.home}/bin"/>
</target>

</project>
```

Comment: where i need to give this code i cant understand